# How to get highest value for each group by checking with two columns value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, inner-join

I have this table test_table below

```
USER_ID | YEAR | MONEY
----------------------
  1     |  0   |  0
  1     | 12   | 12
  1     | 48   | 12
  2     | 15   | 15
  2     | 10   | 20
  3     |  0   |  0
```

So I am trying to return the row which has the highest money. For example, the row return would be like this

```
USER_ID | YEAR | MONEY
----------------------
  1     | 12   | 12
  1     | 48   | 12
  2     | 10   | 20
  3     |  0   |  0
```

But because User ID 1 has the same value for money, I would like to check for the highest year of that money amount and return the result. The expected result should be

```
USER_ID | YEAR | MONEY
----------------------
  1     | 48   | 12
  2     | 10   | 20
  3     |  0   |  0
```

Is it possible to get row like this?

Here is the link to test your query online
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e5660/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f0f0241e64ccd087ca1884505583873)**

```
select userid, moneyval,max(year) as year
from
(
select * from t a
where moneyval in 
(select max(moneyval) from t b where a.userid=b.userid)
)A group by userid, moneyval
```

OUTPUT:

```
userid  moneyval    year
1        12          48
2        20          10
3        0           0
```

Comment: This query will only return 2 rows. The query will skip row id 2 based on my expected table result. You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e5660/1

Comment: Thanks! This works but based on my actual table. Some rows are skipped. Im gonna log another question based on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists to get the rows with maximum values in money (and year):

```
  select t.*
  from test_table t 
  where not exists (
    select 1 from test_table
    where userid = t.userid and (
      money > t.money or (money = t.money and year > t.year)
    )  
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q4LWRyjpFnWEfewBrS2EfK/1).
Results:

```
| userid | money | year |
| ------ | ----- | ---- |
| 1      | 12    | 48   |
| 2      | 20    | 10   |
| 3      | 0     | 0    |
```